# Application as an API in WSO2API 1.7

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I have published an application as API in WSO2 api manager.So when subscriber visits the wso2 store and opens the api,should be able to see the result(call to the restful service deployed) as though a JSON response.Currently as the subscriber opens the api, they are only able to see the API details with the Production and Sandbox urls which they do not understand how to be used.Isn't there a way I may allow them to open up into a front end UI message which the user understands to go ahead rather than arriving at a new place which is not understood.or any better way of handling it.

Answer (score 0):

Product you need for this is [WSO2 APP Manager](http://wso2.com/products/app-manager/). not API manager

Comment: I am getting the below error as I try to login to the Publisher with the user created in the management console `SAML 2.0 based Single Sign-On
Error when processing the authentication request!
Please try login again.` I have commented out the SSO configuration in the `app-manager.xml` ans `sso-idp-config.xml` since it earlier complained about `404 error - publisher/acs not found`.How to use this without the SSO configuration?